# XML to CSV with data header using Liquid Data Mapper

Tags: liquid-xml

I have an XML file that describes a header and a list. I need to generate a CSV file where the first line of the file is constructed from the header information and the subsequent lines of the file constructed from the list. The header has a different number of columns to the list items.

This is easy to do with xsl. How can I do it with the data mapper using the .NET mapping engine?

A simple example to explain. XSD of input xml

```
<xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="A" />
            <xs:element name="B" />
            <xs:element name="Line" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="C" />
                        <xs:element name="D" />
                        <xs:element name="E" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

An Example Input XML

```
 <Root>
     <A>Header Value</A>
     <B>112233</B>
     <Line>
         <C>22</C>
         <D>Fred</D>
         <E>1</E>
     </Line>
     <Line>
         <C>34</C>
         <D>Jim</D>
         <E>2</E>
     </Line>
     <Line>
         <C>42</C>
         <D>Amanda</D>
         <E>1</E>
     </Line>
     <Line>
         <C>1267</C>
         <D>Vickie</D>
         <E>2</E>
     </Line>
 </Root>
```

Required Text Output:

```
 Header Value|112233
 22|Fred|1
 34|Jim|2
 42|Amanda|1
 1267|Vickie|2
```

Generating either

```
 Header Value|112233
```

or

```
 22|Fred|1
 34|Jim|2
 42|Amanda|1
 1267|Vickie|2
```

as individual csv files is easy (as it should be) but how can I can't see how to produce the required file other than resorting back to xslt.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a transform that looks something like this if you want to be able to dynamically set the headers.

[image]

You double up the 'Row' inputs using the 'Duplicate' option

[image]

Before you do that you need to tweak your schema. The input values A-E need typing (note the `type="xs:string"`).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid Studio 2019 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="A" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="B" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="Line" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="C" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="D" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="E" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This will give you output data that looks like this (note it always outputs 3 columns, so you get a trailing '|').

```
Header Value|112233|
22|Fred|1
34|Jim|2
42|Amanda|1
1267|Vickie|2
```

If you just want the data and no header then you can just connect it up like this

[image]